# I'd like to reduce telemetry in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

when VSCode is running I see

```
[master *%]> ps aux | grep enableTelemetry
pl       29331  4.8  3.7 1326800 223568 ?      Sl   Mar10   2:07 /usr/share/code/code --max-old-space-size=3072 /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js --useInferredProjectPerProjectRoot --enableTelemetry --cancellationPipeName /tmp/vscode-typescript1000/a21f3a40b2e3452a6c26/tscancellation-31b196e0b1a09b5f8b22.tmp* --globalPlugins typescript-vscode-sh-plugin --pluginProbeLocations /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features --locale en --noGetErrOnBackgroundUpdate --validateDefaultNpmLocation
pl       29366  0.2  1.4 573640 85360 ?        Sl   Mar10   0:05 /usr/share/code/code /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/typingsInstaller.js --globalTypingsCacheLocation /home/pl/.cache/typescript/3.8 --enableTelemetry --typesMapLocation /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/typesMap.json --validateDefaultNpmLocation
```

while settigs are

```
~/.config/Code/User/settings.json:
  32:   "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
  33:   "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
```

it doesn’t really scare me)) , just don’t like that they hide it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `enableTelemetry` command line flag you see being used for TypeScript [does not mean any telemetry is being uploaded](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79703#issuecomment-524512338), it only makes the TypeScript server that powers VS Code's JS/TS IntelliSense send telemetry data back to the main VS Code process. Depending on your settings, VS Code then itself may then upload this telemetry data.

Whether or not any telemetry is upload by VS Code or its built-in extensions is controlled by the [normal VS Code telemetry settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/telemetry). Again though, the TypeScript server will alway runs with `--enableTelemetry` regardless of any user settings because the flag is independent of telemetry being uploaded.

You can check this by building VS Code from source. Network monitors will show no telemetry is being sent from your build, but the `--enableTelemetry` flag will still be used